# Why SQLite data isn't inserted?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm making an app and I'm adding an Easter Egg to it. I'm trying to make it so that when the user finds the Easter Egg, an integer is inserted into a SQLite column. The value is not being inserted into the column.

```
public boolean easterEggWasFound(int wasFound) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_6, wasFound);
    guessTheNumber.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

Whole SQLite Helper class:

```
public class SQLDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "guessthenumber.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "guess_the_number_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_2 = "TRIES";
public static final String COL_3 = "DIFFICULTY";
public static final String COL_4 = "DEFAULT_NAME";
public static final String COL_5 = "SUCCESS";
public static final String COL_6 = "EASTER_EGG";
SQLiteDatabase guessTheNumber = this.getWritableDatabase();


public SQLDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase guessTheNumber) {
    guessTheNumber.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME TEXT, TRIES INTEGER, DIFFICULTY TEXT, DEFAULT_NAME TEXT, SUCCESS INTEGER, EASTER_EGG INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase guessTheNumber, int i, int i1) {
    guessTheNumber.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(guessTheNumber);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, int tries, String difficulty, int success) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, tries);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, difficulty);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, success);
    long result = guessTheNumber.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return result != -1;

}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    String[] columns = {COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_5};
    return guessTheNumber.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
}
public void removeAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME);
}


public boolean updateDefaultNameData(String defaultName) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //I have to delete the previous number because in the method, it
    //chooses only the first name in the row
    //This should never contain more than one name
    contentValues.put(COL_4, defaultName);
    guessTheNumber.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, null, null);
    //guessTheNumber.insert(COL_4, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getDefaultNameData() {
    String[] columns = {COL_4};
    return guessTheNumber.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public boolean easterEggWasFound() {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_6, "1");
    guessTheNumber.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, null, null);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getIsEasterEggFound() {
    String[] easterColumns = {COL_6};
    return guessTheNumber.query(TABLE_NAME, easterColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

Please tell me why the data is not being inserted.

Comment: hi Friend,Kindly provide provide complete code of your database class thanks..

Comment: Ok, I added the whole class @Abdul Wahab.

Comment: I bet on no such column(as you added new)  ... asked bazillion times - google for "when onCreate and onUpgrade are called" ... also there is a typo in your onUpgrade

Comment: I don't see a typo... Can you please tell me what it is @Selvin?

Comment: Space us missing

Comment: Ok, I see what you are talking about thank you

Answer (score -2):

Same problem happen to me while insertion in database,After lot of googling and Debugging i found the solution,

> here is the solution please Capital first letter of Table and database
>   name in your code

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "guessthenumber.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "guess_the_number_table";
```

change to this

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Guessthenumber.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Uess_the_number_table";
```

Comment: Umm, is that a link?

Comment: So what is your solution?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that

Comment: It will not solve your problem .. it is obviously just an example of Million Monkeys Programming Style ... table names and files are case insensitive

Comment: Ok, I'll keep mokeying. Thanks everyone!